# What's the meaning of tease here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found [this sentence](http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2013/10/02/meet_the_guy_who_s_been_told_he_s_non_essential_three_times_south_korea_wants_mo).

But "tease" doesn't make any sense here? This is a news site so it shouldn't mean "make fun of" but I can't seem to find the meaning that fits this context. What does it mean here? Am I missing anything here?

> if you have a report you want **teased**, a piece of news, or a good
>   tidbit, send it to us early for maximum **tease**. Remember, if you
>   see something, say something

Comment: Which news site is this? Could you post the complete context.

Comment: This is the site.http://www.foreignpolicy.com/articles/2013/10/02/meet_the_guy_who_s_been_told_he_s_non_essential_three_times_south_korea_wants_mo

Comment: @kih1930 When someone asks you for the link to the source, please edit into your answer rather than adding a comment. Better yet, just include the source in every question you post, because you're always going to be asked for it.

Comment: The link, @WendiKidd is not really helpful, you need to be registered in order to access the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a great question! Here, *tease* means to "draw attention to," but it's a slangy jargon use of the word that might be hard to find in dictionaries. A lot of dictionaries I checked didn't list this usage of the word, but I managed to find one that did. [Macmillan Def. #3](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tease_13) says:

> **tease** `informal` something that is designed to make people interested in an event that will happen or in a product that will become available later

So, if you want a report *teased*, that means you want it to get a lot of attention. Think of something on the verge of going viral. "Send it to us for maximum tease" means that we (whoever "us" is) will attract a lot of attention to the story or product.

It's not a common usage of the word, but I was able to discern what the writers were getting at.

Comment: OP's citation is drifting even further away from the "core" meaning than the closest variant I know of. In tv-land jargon, to *tease a program*, for example, can mean to mention it just before the commercial break that precedes it. Or you can *tease next week's episode* in a soap opera, by showing a few clips from it at the end of *this week's* episode. But at least those usages really do have a reasonable connection with *excite interest, then deliver [originally, **fail** to deliver] satisfaction*. OP's citation seems to simply mean *advertise, promote*. I see no "delayed gratification".

Answer (score 1):

In the [wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tease#Verb) for *tease*, sense 6 is appropriate:

> To entice, to tempt.

Also see sense 3 at [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tease):

> To arouse hope, desire, or curiosity in without affording satisfaction.

Presumably the news site will publicize a report (ie,  “tease” for it) for some time before making the report actually available.